# How to set angular form logics?

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I have a data structure to post my api like following.

```
{
    name: string,
    price: number,
    allowedMinPirce: number,
    allowedMaxPrice: number
}
```

So I have creted a reactive form for this model.

```
myForm = this.fb.group({
    name: ['', Validators.required],
    price: ['', Validators.required],
    allowedMinPirce: ['', Validators.required],
    allowedMaxPrice: ['', Validators.required],
});
```

The fields are required as I set. But I have some other validation logics.

```
price filed should be bigger than 0,
price filed shloud be between allowedMinPirce and allowedMaxPrice,
```

So where can I put these kind of validation logics? (And I need to show alerts user.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this...

```
myForm = this.fb.group({
    name: ['', Validators.required],
    price: ['', [
                 Validators.required,
                 Validators.min(this.form.value.allowedMinPrice),
                 Validators.max(this.form.value.allowedMaxPrice)
                 ]],
    allowedMinPrice: ['', Validators.required],
    allowedMaxPrice: ['', Validators.required],
});
```

For displaying alert messages,

```
<span *ngIf="myForm.get('price').invalid">Enter a valid price</span>
```

Comment: price property should be beyween allowedMinPrice and allowedMaxPrice that user typed. Not specified before.

Answer (score 0):

If you use [angular material](https://material.angular.io/) you can use a custom `errorStateMatcher` class and a custom `validator` function to earn this functionality. Like in [my example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yhbuqn-t88wcq?file=app%2Finput-error-state-matcher-example.ts).

You can use only the `validator` function. Like in [this example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mxwfj7?file=src%2Fapp%2Finput-overview-example.ts).

Comment: No I am not using material.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try this ?

```js
myForm = this.fb.group({
    name: ['', Validators.required],
    price: ['', [
                  Validators.required,
                  Validators.min(this.form.value.allowedMinPirce), 
                  Validators.max(this.form.value.allowedMaxPrice)
                ]
           ],
    allowedMinPirce: ['', Validators.required],
    allowedMaxPrice: ['', Validators.required],
});
```